# pure shell complex substitution in variable

Tags: bash, shell, ksh, variable-substitution

Is there any way to substitute text in variables on several patterns at time or even using back reference?

For example, I have `FILE=filename.ext` and I want to change it to `filename_sometext.ext`. But I don't know that file extension is `.ext`. All I know about it is that extension is after last dot.
So I can do it in two steps:

```
EXT=${FILE##*.}
FILE=${FILE%.*}_sometext.$EXT
```

Can I do it on one step (something like `${FILE/.\(*\)/_sometext.\1}` [that doesn't work])?

By the way I need to do it in pure shell without `sed`/`awk`/etc. My shell is `ksh`, but if there is way to do it with bashisms I'd like to know it too.

Comment: I assume you mean `ksh88` not `ksh93`?

Comment: What if the file name contains multiple dots?

Comment: I mean ksh93. Does it matter so much? And extension is after last dot, it doesn't matter if multiple dots appear before.

Comment: Yes, it matters, `ksh88` is what most people mean when they say `ksh`, and it doesn't support many features that are specific to `ksh93`.  Hence why I asked. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Bash Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) says that the variable (`FILE` in your example) must be a parameter name.  So they don't nest.  And the last part of `${param/pattern/replacement}` must be a string.  So back references aren't supported.

My only advice is to use

```
${EXT:+.$EXT}
```

to avoid adding a trailing dot if the file has no extension.

---

UPDATE

Apparently back references are supported in [ksh93](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh.html).

So you could use something like

```
FILE="${FILE/@(.*)/_something\1}"
```

Comment: I got information about back reference and nested substitution. Thank you.

Comment: Your `${FILE/@(.*)/_something\1}` would be like `${FILE/./_something.}` and change the _first_ occurrence of `.`. You'd need `${FILE/%.*([^.])/_something\0}` or `${FILE/@(*)./\1_something.}` to match on the last one like `${FILE%.*}` would.

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case I think `FILE=${FILE%.*}_sometext.${FILE##*.}` would do the job.

Comment: Yeah, it did the job, but I think my example was a little wrong for that.

Answer (score 0):

#### Variables.

In any shell, you could concatenate variables or values:

```sh
$ a=One; b=Two; c=Three
$ d="$a$b$c"; echo $d
OneTwoThree
```

The `${parameter%word}` type of structures [is POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/chap2.html) have been supported in most shells for a long time.
Assuming `FILE=filename.ext`, you could do:

```sh
$ FILE="${FILE%.*}_sometext.${FILE##*.}"; echo "$FILE"
filename_sometext.ext
```

That is one line (as requested) and works on most shells.

---

It is also possible to use variables (even with several dots):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
FILE=file.one.name.ext
ADDTEXT="_sometext"
EXT="${FILE##*.}"
echo "EXT=$EXT"
echo "final FILE=${FILE%.*}${ADDTEXT}.$EXT"
```

Or, in just one line:

```sh
ONEFILE=${FILE%.*}${ADDTEXT}.${FILE##*.}
echo "one   FILE=$ONEFILE"
```

---

#### Pattern substitution

What gets tricky is trying to use `${parameter/pattern/string}` «Pattern substitution.»

A variable works in many shells (even busybox ash):

```sh
NEWTEXT="${ADDTEXT}.${FILE##*.}"
echo "ash   FILE=${FILE/.*/${NEWTEXT}}"
```

But not in older `sh`ells.

---

Only for `FILE=filename.ext`:
This works in bash (and ksh, ksh93, mksh, zsh) but not in ash, dash, sh or csh

```sh
echo "bash  FILE=${FILE/%.*/${ADDTEXT}.${FILE##*.}}"
```

Note that it is using the `%` character to indicate a match at the end of the parameter (but, sadly it is greedy and eats all dots in `FILE=file.one.name.ext`).

#### Conclusion

The best method to control how greedy is the substitution is to use separate variables (as opposed to some from of «Pattern substitution.»)

Answer (score 0):

```
FILE="${FILE%.*}_sometext${FILE#"${FILE%.*}"}"
```

If the shell variable `$FILE` contains a `.` the above command will reassign to it the old value less everything following the last `.` then *`_sometext`* and last the old value's last `.` and everything after.

And so:

```sh
FILE=some.dot
FILE="${FILE%.*}_sometext${FILE#"${FILE%.*}"}"
printf %s\\n "$FILE"
```

---

```
some_sometext.dot
```

If the shell variable `$FILE` does *not* contain a dot, then the *`_sometext`* string is merely appended to the end of the old value:

```sh
FILE=no_dots_at_all
FILE="${FILE%.*}_sometext${FILE#"${FILE%.*}"}"
printf %s\\n "$FILE"
```

---

```
no_dots_at_all_sometext
```

This is importantly different behavior than you might get if you did not nest the parameter expansion as I do on the end there:

```
FILE=no_dots_at_all
FILE="${FILE%.*}_sometext${FILE##*.}"
printf %s\\n "$FILE"
```

---

```
no_dots_at_all_sometextno_dots_at_all
```

When you nest the parameter expansion it is evaluated inside to outside, and so the first thing that happens is:

```
for    FILE in    some.dot no_dots_at_all
do     printf %s\\n '${FILE#'"${FILE%.*}"'}'
done
```

---

```
${FILE#some}
${FILE#no_dots_at_all}
```

...the shell removes any matched bits and uses the remains as the pattern to strip from the outer expansion. And so when there *aren't* any matched bits and the variable expands in full the outer expansion strips away *all* of the variable rather than substituting it into your expression twice.